# UItableviewcell is visible back to navigation bar in ios

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uinavigationbar, gradient

I am using the below code to set the gradient colour to `navigationBar`. But after applying the gradient colour my table view cell scrolls back to the `navigationBar` and content of the top `cell` is bit visible back to the `navigationBar`.

```
let gradient: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        let navigationBar = self.navigationController?.navigationBar.bounds
        let statusBar = UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame
        let gradientBounds = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, (navigationBar?.size.width)!+statusBar.size.width, (navigationBar?.size.height)!+statusBar.size.height)
        gradient.frame = (gradientBounds)
        gradient.colors = [UIColor.redColor().CGColor, UIColor.blackColor().CGColor]
        gradient.locations = [0.0, 1.0]
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(gradient.bounds.size);
        gradient.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        let backImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Default
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(backImage, forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
```

[image]

Comment: Try including a screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Navigation bars are translucent by default and even if they were not - that'd still be the first place to verify. Setting a solid background image doesn't make it opaque, in addition to that you'll need to set the navigation bar `translucent` property through code or at the Interface Builder.

Comment: self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Default. In this line even i tried by changing the UIBarStyle as translucent instead of default. But It doesn't give any impact. 

If I remove the gradient then this table view content is no longer at the back side of navigation bar.

Why this issue is only when applying the gradient colours?

Comment: Read the answer again, it doesn't say anything about changing the value of `barStyle`, if you need more details of why the `translucent` should be used, refer to documentation of `UIBarStyle`.